# Leverage the font-display CSS in Bulma

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify, bulma

According to Google PageSpeed Insights font-display should be used to ensure text visibility while the fonts are loading.

How can I achieve that since I'm using bulma?
I'm loading my font from google, added `&display=swap` but i still get the error on PageSpeed Insights

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700&display=swap')`

What can I do to fix it?